# Can I use the Clipboard.SetContent function in a CLI app?

Tags: rust, windows-runtime

The function is executed without error and returns `Ok(())`, but the text is not pushed into the clipboard:

```
pub fn copy_text(text_fragment: winrt::HString) -> winrt::Result<()> {
    let data_package = DataPackage::new()?;
    data_package.set_text(text_fragment)?;
    Clipboard::set_content(data_package)
}
```

The documentation about the Windows runtime API has the following statement for the [`Clipboard.SetContent(DataPackage)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.setcontent?view=winrt-19041) function:

> Use this method after creating and defining a `DataPackage` with the data you want to put on the clipboard. Call this method only when the application is in the foreground, or when a debugger is attached.

Is there any way I can use that function without a UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it's officially supported on a non-UI thread, but it seems to work if you add a call to `flush` as follows:

```rust
use windows::application_model::data_transfer::*;

fn main() -> winrt::Result<()> {
    let content = DataPackage::new()?;
    content.set_text("hello world from Rust")?;
    Clipboard::set_content(content)?;
    Clipboard::flush()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

The `flush` method ensures that the content is copied onto the clipboard and will remain there even if the sending application/process terminates.